# How to clear selected elements from array

Tags: c#

Hi I'm creating a program that holds three arrays one for the persons last name, one for the points scored and one for the player number. I made a delete method that is suppose to when the user enters a player number delete the player number, last name and points for the player number entered, However when I enter a players number to delete the player data it clears the entire array when I  want to be able to clear the the player number, last name and points of the player number entered but just these items and not the entire array. I am not sure on how to do this.

Some help or guidance in the right direction would really help please and thank you

```
static void ProcessDelete( Int32[] playerNumbers, ref Int32 playerCount,  String[] playerLastName,  Int32[] playerPoints)
    {

        Int32[] newArray = new Int32[playerNumbers.Length]; String[] newArray2 = new String[playerLastName.Length]; Int32[] newArray3 = new Int32[playerPoints.Length];

        int index = Array.IndexOf(playerNumbers, 0);


        {
            for (int i = 0; i < playerNumbers.Length; i++)

                playerNumbers[i] = 0;

        }


        for (int i = 0; index < playerLastName.Length; index++)


                playerLastName[i] = " ";



        for (int i = 0; i < playerPoints.Length; i++)

            playerPoints[i] = 0;

    }



    static void DeletePlayer(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
    {
        int player;// Player number to delete
        int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
        if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
        {

            player = GetPositiveInteger("\nDelete Player: please enter the player's number");
            playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCount);


           if (playerindex != -1)
            {

                {

                    Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastName[playerindex], playerPoints[playerindex]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Succesfully Deleted");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    ProcessDelete( playerNumbers, ref playerCount,  playerLastName, playerPoints);
                }
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: player not found");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: the roster is empty");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Just a suggestion, Create a class `Player` with properties `PlayerNumber`, `Name` and `Score` and maintain a `List<Player>`, instead of having multiple arrays and managing them based on index.

Comment: That isn't a good pattern - use a single object.

Comment: fix your usage of `{ }` as well don't add unnecessary brackets for when they are not needed please clean up your code and reformat it as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *right* answer is to do what Habib suggested and create a Player class with these three properties and use a single list.

But, to answer the question you asked, your problem is that you are looping through every element in the array with your for-loops and resetting everything.  If you just want to clear out the arrays for a single player, your ProcessDelete method should use the index that you are obtaining in the DeletePlayer method.

```c#
static void ProcessDelete( Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastName,  Int32[] playerPoints, Int32 playerIndex)
{
  playerNumbers[playerIndex] = 0;
  playerLastName[playerIndex] = " ";
  playerPoints[playerIndex] = 0;
}
```